# Readfile excel startrow and endrow

Tags: c#, excel

I want get values column of file excel 
without I fix strat row and end row

Example 
Data
[Data](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4XQXKz8Z1RWNTQwdlo3dmpCMlU/preview)

Code

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:B6]", oledbConn);
```

Output

```
------------------------------------
PERSONID     |      CITY PERSON
------------------------------------
2            |         bkk
------------------------------------
1            |         japan
------------------------------------
1            |         japan
------------------------------------
2            |         bkk
------------------------------------
```

**but** I need all data without I fix startrow  don't fix endrow 
(fix startrow don't fix endrow because I don't know rowend Data is a big )

[Big Data](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4XQXKz8Z1RWNnRsYVpRWDZzS00/preview)

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:?]", oledbConn);
```

What should I do

Comment: I need value end of row (endrow) for file excel 
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:?]"
'?' : I don't know endrow in file execl because data is a big [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4XQXKz8Z1RWNnRsYVpRWDZzS00/preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear to me, but i try to answer.
I understand that you need to read data from an excel file and you do not know exactly the range of this data, maybe because a user added more rows.
There are several ways to do this, but as far as i know, there is now way to auto detect it with a oledb command statement. What we always did is we modified the excel file slightly and added a named range to the data range.
So just select A2:B6 and then set a name on the top left corner (it is written how to do this here: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm)
Then you can do the select on the named range, e.g. "SELECT * FROM [RANGE_NAMED]".
The good thing now is:
excel is quite intelligent and if the user addes row directly after the range or in the middle of the range, the range gets extended :)

maybe this helps.